# WSARecv sometimes return "invalid handle (error no 6)" for a socket associated with an IOCP port. (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, network-programming, iocp

I'm trying to write a server which can support many clients connections simultaneously so I'm trying to do it with IOCP. So let me brief about my code flow and then I can explain my problem. First of all, server is opening a port for listening and waiting on an "accept" call for new incoming connections. For reference I have used same code as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) So it accepts every new incoming connection and returns a new socket descriptor (sd), and then it marks as nonblocking with:

```
arg = 1;
ioctlsocket(sd, FIONBIO, &arg);
```

and then enable TCP_NODELAY:

```
level = IPPROTO_TCP;
optName = TCP_NODELAY;
value = 1;
setsockopt(sd, level, optName, (const char*)&value, sizeof(value));
```

thereafter associating with an IOCP port as:

```
CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)sd, iocp_port, (DWORD)completion_key, 4);
```

completion_key is a class object which is nothing but a container, it contains data buffer, overlapped-buffer, query-type recv/send etc.
and in last issuing a read call:

```
WSARecv(sd, wsabuf, 1, &bytes, &flags, overlapped, NULL);
```

wsabuf and overlapped are part of completion_key object.

In 90% cases it works fine i.e. when there is some incoming data available on this socket "GetQueuedCompletionStatus" gets unblocked and it has valid data. But sometimes WSARecv call returns with an error and GetLastError() returns 6 which is "invalid handle" error. I'm bit bewildered why it's happening so.

The way I'm creating an iocp port:

```
iocp_port = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 0);
```

and there are threads which are waiting on "GetQueuedCompletionStatus".

Comment: Where is the overlapped block?  You need a different one for each WSARecv call, both in the first one you issue in the accept() loop and those that you, (presumably), issue in the handler threads after handling a completion message.

Comment: It's common in OO to have the OVL struct as a member of the buffer class, so as to ensure that each overlapped I/O call has its own OVL block.

Comment: yes, I know that. completion_key is a class object which contains an overlapped buffer. So for each WSARecv call a different overlapped buffer is passed, I'm updating above content with same.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you know what you're doing (you kinda have to if you're using IOCP), but I'll mention it regardless. Forget everything you know about *anything* once you reach your `GetQueueCompletionStatus()` loop. All too often I see people go through all the setup, fire up their GQCS loop, then utterly forget that when that function returns with success the *only* thing you can rely on is the LPOVERLAPPED returned with it. Having read what I just wrote, i realize if someone has never used IOCP its going to be greek to them. But if you have, you will know exactly what I'm referring to.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you @WhozCraig, I'm relying on what lpoverlapped is returning when GetQueueCompletionStatus() gets unblocked. It's like: if return value is 0 and overlapped == NULL then it's unable to fetch an event and if overlapped != NULL then there is some issue with corresponding socket. If return value is != 0 and bytescount > 0 then we have valid data in buffer.

Comment: @WhozCraig - heh, yes, I use only that.  I load a buffer+OVL instance pointer into the hEvent field and cast it back in the handler thread.  Each buffer has a pointer to its socket object so I can issue another WSARecv.  Not sure what I would do on 64-bit:(

Comment: Ok. I kinda figured. just making sure. you'd be amazed how common that mistake happens. thanks for verifying. You may want to include the preamble and primary front-side of your GQCS loop in this. (and I'm not sure you should be double-dutiing that `hEvent` field; you have your own struct, may as well use it.)

Comment: I'm not using hEvent field of overlapped buffer, am maintaining a variable in completion-key object itself to track read/write events. I'm wondering how is it related to "invalid handle" error which it throws on first WSARecv call, however it works most of the time.

Comment: You don't show enough code for anyone to work out what you're doing wrong. Chances are your socket or IOCP is being closed before the call that fails but without all your code we can't tell - and I don't want to look at all your code ;)

Comment: @WhozCraig, @Martin James, this is a bit off topic and I may be misunderstanding your conversation, but... You can just derive a structure from an `OVERLAPPED` and pass the derived structure to your `WSASend()`, etc. and then cast back after getting your `OVERLAPPED` pointer back from `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`. The pointer that you get back is guaranteed to be the one you pass in (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/17/10106259.aspx) and so there's no need to muck around with reusing fields inside of the `OVERLAPPED` structure itself

Comment: I forgot to update my solution here, please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I monitored all system calls which were happening in background. WSARecv internally calls NtDeviceIoControlFile and there is an argument "Event" which is same as what is passed in lpOverlapped structure of WSARecv as [hEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I wasn't setting hEvent to NULL, so it was taking some garbage value, when it was NULL then NtDeviceIoControlFile returned successfully and for other cases it returned "INVALID_HANDLE" error. Unfortunately, it was NULL most of the time.

Comment: Well done for tracking down the problem. It's always wise to zero out data structures, such as `OVERLAPPED` before using them and explicitly set all of the values that you need to set. If you're working in C++ then a simple wrapper class that derives from OVERLAPPED and does a `ZeroMemory()` to initialise it in the ctor is usually enough to prevent these kinds of mistakes...

Comment: nik_kgp, how did you "monitor the system calls in the background" - can you share please?  Thanks!